# Trouble Understanding Joining Tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Please see attached Tables image.

The question I have:

Find the top 5 occupations that borrowed the most in 2016

The code I have:

```
select c.occupation, count(*) no_mostborrow
from client c
Inner Join client c on c.clientID = b.clientID
where b.borrowDate >= '2016-01-01' and b.borrowDate < '2017-01-01'
group by c.clientoccupation, c.clientid
order by count(*) asc
limit 5
```

I feel like I am missing something here but I am not sure what. I am sure I am completely off. Thank you so much for your time.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you think your code is working?  What is your question?

Comment: You should `Inner Join borrower b`, not `Inner Join client c`, not `group by c.clientid` and `order by no_mostborrow desc`

Comment: I am unsure if that would produce what the question is asking. After review I know I need to change asc > desc. I don't know if grouping by c.clientoccupation, c.clientid is correct or if I should be using something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you only want `occupation` in the `group by`.  And the `join` needs to be correct:

```
select c.occupation, count(*) as no_mostborrow
from client c join
     borrower b
     on c.clientid = b.clientid
where b.borrowDate >= '2016-01-01' and b.borrowDate < '2017-01-01'
group by c.clientoccupation
order by count(*) asc
limit 5
```

Comment: @Nick . . . Well, a self-join won't do it.  I guess the correct join is needed.